# Groovy: JSON Parsing

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper

Seeing an interesting issue, not sure this is to do with parser or the way it suppose to parse. Any help is appreciated

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def dMatch = '''[{"match":{"keyId":"A-102161-application"}},{"match":{"keyId":"A-102162-application"}},{"match":{"keyId":"A-102163-application"}},{"match":{"keyId":"A-102164-application"}},{"match":{"keyId":"A-102165-application"}}]'''

println "T1:: List: " + dMatch

def parser = new JsonSlurper()
def exclude = parser.parseText(dMatch)
println "T2:: Obj: " + exclude.toString()

println "----------------------------------------------------"
```

**Output :**

```
T1:: List: [{"match":{"keyId":"A-102161-application"}},
            {"match":{"keyId":"A-102162-application"}},
            {"match":{"keyId":"A-102163-application"}},
            {"match":{"keyId":"A-102164-application"}},
            {"match":{"keyId":"A-102165-application"}}]
```

```
T2:: Obj: *[[match:[keyId:A-102161-application]], 
            [match:[keyId:A-102162-application]],  
            [match:[keyId:A-102163-application]],  
            [match:[keyId:A-102164-application]],  
            [match:[keyId:A-102165-application]]]*
```

The parsed object supposed to be same as the string but all the values were converted as array list of map.

Any idea why this is generating object like this ? When this is sent to camunda it complains

> org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: Cannot serialize object in variable 'exclude': groovy.json.internal.LazyMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JsonSlurperClassic()` - it produces standard `HashMap` that is serializable.

And if you want to convert object back to json use Json output.toJson(obj)

Comment: Still seeing - 


> SPIN/JACKSON-JSON-01007 Cannot construct java type from string 'groovy.json.internal.LazyMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>'

Comment: Tried building the list + map objects 

`def list = []
mapObj.eachWithIndex { obj, index -> 
    Map match = [:]
    Map app = [:]
    
    app.put('keyId', obj.key)
    match.put('match', app)
    println index + ": " + match
    
    list.push(match)
    
}`

still seeing serialization issue -  exclude in the error is list object from the above. 
`io.vertx.serviceproxy.ServiceException: Cannot deserialize object in variable 'exclude': SPIN/JACKSON-JSON-01007 Cannot construct java type from string 'groovy.json.internal.LazyMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>'
`

Comment: you have to ask clear question. it's not about `groovy json parser` - because this one works fine. your question seems how to set variable into camunda process. you have to provide all information how you are doing this... i advice you to edit the question and provide all information. or even better to ask a new question